# Guice: injector in provider

Tags: task, guice, provider, executor

I know that generally injector should be used only once in all application (on startup). But i have following use case. I inject task implementation for Executor, and then inside that task i have dependency (lets say `FileHandler`) that has to be instantiated each time. I know the way is to inject provider (lets say `FileHandlerProvider`) that will return new instance each time requested. The problem is that `FileHandler` has a lot of dependencies of it own (lets say `Parser`, `OutputPrinter`...). Now those also need new instance each time (because implementations could have some state, for example counters, and on next thread run reusing same instance would be a problem). The thing is that after provider is injected the same instance of provider is reused, so new `FileHandler` is always created with same `Parser` and `OuputPrinter`. The solution could be again to inject `ParserProvider`  and `OutputPrinterProvider` instead of Parser and `OuputPrinter` in `FileHandlerProvider`, but thats just not right, it gets too complicated soon, because there are more dependencies. The only simple solution I see now could be to use Injector in `FileHandlerProvider`, that would return new instance `FileHandler` (and new instances of dependencies). Or maybe there is another more elegant solution in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just bind `FileHandler` and its dependencies all with default scope (i.e. no scope). Then inject `Provider<FileHandler>` and use its `get()` every time you need a new `FileHandler` instance. Since `FileHandler` has no scope, each time `get()` is called a new instance of `FileHandler` needs to be created... and since its dependencies also have no scope, a new instance of each of them needs to be created each time as well. It should work just the way you want.

I think the thing that you're (maybe) missing here is that you don't need to write any of these providers yourself... just inject `Provider<FileHandler>` and Guice will do it all for you.

**Edit:** Here's a small class I wrote that demonstrates the dependencies of a class getting created new each time an instance of that class is created.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
    injector.getInstance(Test.class);
  }

  @Inject public Test(Provider<FileHandler> fileHandlerProvider) {
    FileHandler fileHandler1 = fileHandlerProvider.get();
    FileHandler fileHandler2 = fileHandlerProvider.get();

    System.out.println("fileHandler1 == fileHandler2? " + 
        (fileHandler1 == fileHandler2));
    System.out.println("fileHandler1.parser == fileHandler2.parser? " + 
        (fileHandler1.parser == fileHandler2.parser));
    System.out.println("fileHandler1.print == fileHandler2.printer? " + 
        (fileHandler1.printer == fileHandler2.printer));
  }

  private static class FileHandler {
    private final Parser parser;
    private final OutputPrinter printer;

    @Inject private FileHandler(Parser parser, OutputPrinter printer) {
      this.parser = parser;
      this.printer = printer;
    }
  }

  private static class Parser {
  }

  private static class OutputPrinter {
  }
}
```

When run, this code prints:

```
fileHandler1 == fileHandler2? false
fileHandler1.parser == fileHandler2.parser? false
fileHandler1.print == fileHandler2.printer? false
```

This shows that not only was a new `FileHandler` instance created each time, new `Parser` and `OutputPrinter` instances were create and injected in to the `FileHandler` each time as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for an answer, but the thing is that even if i don't create providers by hand - dependencies of FileHandler are same reused instances. This is probably happening because Task is created only once, then it has injected provider (also only one instance), provider creates new instance of FileHandler but always uses same instances of FileHandler dependencies, since they were injected into provider by guice on its creation. So i quess there is no other way, just use injector in provider...

Comment: @Ignas: I'm not sure what you mean. Dependencies should not be reused unless they have some scope that causes them to be reused or you're doing something that specifically causes them to be reused. See my example demonstrating that.

Comment: Hey, it was my mistake when I was debugging. It is working. Thanks! :)